# Запятая, или тире, или же-с двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Запятая, или тире, или двоеточие?

> Самое главное (?) чтобы ты не пришёл не вовремя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Самое главное — чтобы ты не пришёл не вовремя* — тире разделяет главные члены.

*Самое главное, чтобы ты не пришёл не вовремя* — запятая разделяет части СПП.

Comment: Оба варианта верны?

Comment: Какая между ними разница?

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Автор решает, что поставить. Если пауза, то ставим тире; если микропауза — запятую.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Я спать. Если ещë какие-то вопросы будут, а я не ответил, значит, я сплю. Вы знаете моë время, если смотрели профиль.

Comment: Утром отвечу, если остались.

Comment: Мне кажется, что, т. к. *самое главное* — подлежащие, а остальное — сказуемое, можно только тире.

Comment: @Леопольд-мэтр Оба варианта можно использовать.